# How to get selected rows of Checkcolumn in a grid

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am trying to get the number of selected rows of a grid.

Grid columns looks like this -

> ```
> columns: [
>     { header: 'Select All', xtype: 'checkcolumn' dataIndex: 'active' },
>     { header: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name' },
>     { header: 'City', dataIndex: 'city' }            
> ]
> ```
>
> When i try to get the selected rows by -
>
> ```
> Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#gdDeliveryDateItemId')[0].getSelectionModel().selected.items
> ```

Is returning nothing.

If i use a checkboxmodel it will work but how to get it in checkcolumn ?

Please suggest me

Comment: I suggest you look into the SelectionModel for the Grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is making use of Grid's store. Get the reference of grid via Ext.ComponentQuery.query method and then

```
grid.getStore().each(function(record){
    if(record.get('active') == true){
        // handle individual records here
    }
});
```

Kindly check developer console for this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1a45).